# The Genus field and Hilbert class field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields

Is there an example of a number field $K$ for which the genus field of $K$ is contained strictly in the Hilbert class field of $K$?

Comment: Any quadratic field with class group that is not an elementary $2$-group, the canonical example probably being $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$.

Comment: @Aurel: Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @GHfromMO I wasnt't sure the question was going to be considered research level. But sure, why not :-)

Comment: @Aurel: Thanks. Perhaps adding a bit of explanation (class field theory etc.) might help the OP. Strictly speaking, the question is not of research level, but it is certainly of "graduate school level", so I think it is appropriate here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $K$ be a quadratic field with class group $\mathrm{Cl}(K)$ such that $\mathrm{Cl}(K)\neq \mathrm{Cl}(K)[2]$. Since the Galois group of the genus field is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Cl}(K)[2]$ and the one of the Hilbert class field to $\mathrm{Cl}(K)$, this provides an example.

The canonical example is probably $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$: it has class number $3$, and its Hilbert class field $H$ is generated over $K$ by a root of $x^3-x-1$. The field $H$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, but its Galois group is $D_3$, so it is not the compositum of $K$ and a cyclic cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.